# When a solaris server has 2 SSHs installed, how to choose which one client is connected to

Tags: ssh, unix, solaris

Currently my solaris server has 2 SSH installed:

- /usr/bin/ssh (Sun_SSH_1.1.6)
- /usr/local/bin/ssh (OpenSSH_5.1p)

When I SSH this solaris server from another, /usr/bin/ssh is responding.
I would like /usr/local/bin/ssh to be the default SSH that respond, how would I do that?

For example, when I run

```
ssh mysolaris -l myname 'ssh -v'
```

I get `OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8j 07 Jan 2009`. I want to get `OpenSSH_5.1p`.

When I SSH log in and display path, this is what I get:
/user/myname/bin:/usr/atria/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/ccs/bin

However, when I do interactive login, this is what I get:
/usr/bin:/bin

Comment: What do you mean? Are you at console of your Solaris and you are trying to use ssh to connect to another machine? Or you mean by "responding", that you try to connect to your Solaris box from outside (in that case it would be a sshd server though)?

Comment: Please fix your terminology. /usr/bin/ssh and /usr/local/bin/ssh don't respond. Also, logging in via ssh is interactive as well. You seem to be asking why your PATH is different when you use two ways to log in - via ssh, and on a terminal that is not connected via network. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know what shell your Solaris account is using, but I would find out which profile sets /user/myname/bin in the PATH, then figure out how the different login methods use different profiles.

Comment: OpenSSH 5.1?!?!  https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.1:   "OpenSSH 5.1 was released on 2008-07-22."  That's why you don't roll your own, put it in `/usr/local` and forget about it for over a decade.  Why are you even bothering to use `ssh` - security is obviously not important to your organization.

Comment: I am connecting my Solaris from a different server. Currently when I run this: ssh mysolaris -l myname 'ssh -v', I get 'OpenSSH_5.1p1. So this means  /usr/bin/ssh is set as the default SSH. I want to change the default SSH to /usr/local/bin/ssh so when  ssh mysolaris -l myname 'ssh -v', I get OpenSSH_5.1p.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to switch a service from a perfectly fine OS-supported installation of `ssh` to one that hasn't been updated for over a decade? (That's probably a huge reason you're not getting any answers...)

Comment: We have a few legacy Solaris servers left that we need to keep, but want to leave alone as much as possible. Our other servers have OpenSSH 8.5 and when I try to SSH from these server to  Solaris servers, the SSH connection fails due to incompatible key exchange method. We tried upgrade the Sun_SSH_1.1.6, but it turned out OpenSSH_5.1p is also there and is compatible with OpenSSH 8.5. That is why I am tying to make OpenSSH_5.1p the default SSH that respond to SSH connection.

Comment: So this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?